# ASP.NET MVC Select and reorder columns in WebGrid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I have following View code:

```
@model IEnumerable<Profiler.Models.Partner>

@{
  var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, defaultSort:"Route ID", rowsPerPage: 50);
}

@grid.GetHtml()
```

And I'd like to select columns in my custom order. How can I do that?